Wordpress Paypal Error "Authentication with PayPal failed: Could not create token."
I'm using woocoomerce plugin "WooCommerce PayPal Payments" when I try to use my live credentials as well as sandbox credentials I always get the error Authentication with PayPal failed: Could not create token. and it keeps loading on checkout page
I tried different plugins also I used different sandbox accounts but the issue is still same, I have disabled all the plugins and I keep only woocommerce and WooCommerce PayPal Payments plugin

Woocommerce questions are off topic for this Stack (see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your best bet would be to ask on the plugin's forum on wordpress.org
